# what does "by = lambda x: lambda y: getattr(y, x)" mean?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

There is a dataFrame named "subset" and the codes are as follows. pd is the nickname of pandas. I can't figure out the meaning of `by = lambda x: lambda y: getattr(y, x)`.

```
pivot = pd.pivot_table(subset, values='count', rows=['date'], cols=['sample'], fill_value=0)
by = lambda x: lambda y: getattr(y, x)
grouped = pivot.groupby([by('year'),by('month')]).sum()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are Python lambdas useful?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890128/why-are-python-lambdas-useful)

Comment: assuming `year` and `month` are columns I am guessing it is doing the same thing as `grouped = pivot.groupby(['year', 'month']).sum()`

Comment: `year` and `month` are not columns. This is the first time they appear in the code and it can run well. There is a column named 'date' in subset and I'm trying to find the relation between them.@StefanoPotter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`by = lambda x: lambda y: getattr(y, x)` is equivalent to the following:

```
def by(x):
    def getter(y):
        return getattr(y, x)
    return getter
```

`getattr(a, b)` gets an attribute with the name `b` from an object named `a`.

So `by('bar')` returns a function that returns the attribute `'bar'` from an object.

`by('bar')(foo)` means `getattr(foo, 'bar')` which is roughly `foo.bar`.

If that doesn't help, let us know which part you're still having trouble with.